# Did not die vs was not dead

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

I need to tell someone that if the guy I am referring to is still alive he would have created many miracles. Are the below two sentences grammatically correct in the before-mentioned context? If there are any differences , could someone explain me with the details.

1. If he did not die,he would have created many miracles.
2. If he was not dead,he would have created many miracles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both correct grammar with similar meanings. The difference is limited to the difference between "He is dead" and "He died" (the difference is current fact/ past act)

You could consider a third option: "He has died" is close to "He is dead", so you could say

> If he hadn't died, ...

That is my prefered form